# How to create a new thread with return value for Android

Tags: android, optimization, thread-safety, structure

I have an activity that I need to run based on the internet status.The problem is the structure. I have many lines in ***// other codes...***

I would like to put them inside onCreate(), not inside handleMessage(). But I don't know how to do.

The structure I am looking for:

```
need a new thread like below:
boolean xxxx() {
    judge internet;
    if internet is ok, return ok;
    else return bad;
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // codes...

    if (xxxx().equals("bad")) return;

    // other codes...

} 
}
```

The structure I have to use:

```
Runnable newTread = new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    // judge net statements
    msg.obj = num;
    handler.sendMessage(msg);
}

};

Handler handler = new Handler() {

@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    switch (msg.num) {
       case internet is ok: // other codes...
       case internet is bad: do nothing           
    }
} 
};

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // codes...

    Thread t= new Thread(newTread);
    t.start();

} 
}
```

Comment: onCreate is a void method put in mind that you cannot execute return from inside it

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to return anything from onCreate(), I try to pass a value from a new thread to onCreate()

Comment: Sorry, I mis-understood. Actually I cannot use return xxx inside onCreate(). But I can use return without xxx inside onCreate(), right?

Comment: if you would like to handle network status without using another thread i have implemented another solution...if you are interested, i could post it..

Comment: tsiro, thanks a lot! But I heard that must access internet in new thread. If I can access net in UI thread, I don't even need to ask this question...

Comment: I guess my question is rare or a hard one?